# reading external XML file

Tags: php, xml

I need to use an external XML file, I've tried different methods to read the file but can't reach what I want.

I used `DOMDocument` `simplexml_load_file`

```
<?

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.isecur1ty.org/InternetThreat/ThreatLevel.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
}

?>
```

But can't get it working with me!!

Here is the XML file:

```
<iS-InternetThreat>
    <level>
        <current>2</current>
        <previous>2</previous>
        <status>same</status>
        <date>09-06-2012</date>
    </level>
    <version>2.5</version>
</iS-InternetThreat>
```

As you can see, there are multi-levels. I need to get the values of each attribute (mainly under "level"), getting the version would be also ok.

Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work about your code?  That information would be extremely helpful to anyone helping you.

Comment: @Vulcan : Check the answers below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, Got it :D

here is the solution, hope anyone can find it useful.

```
<?

    $file = 'http://www.isecur1ty.org/InternetThreat/ThreatLevel.xml';
    if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
        exit('Failed to open '.$file);
    print_r($xml);  echo "<br />";
    echo "Current Level : " . $xml->level->current . "<br />" .
        "Previous Level : " . $xml->level->previous . "<br />" . 
        "Status : " . $xml->level->status . "<br />" . 
        "Date : " . $xml->level->date . "<br />" . 
        "Version : " . $xml->version . "<br />"

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Access them like this:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.isecur1ty.org/InternetThreat/ThreatLevel.xml");
    echo $xml->level->date;
?>
```

Comment: I just figured it out just before you added the answer :) .. Thanks.